# Boundary Condition for Perfect Conductor in Uniform Magnetic Field

Tags: boundary-conditions, classical-electrodynamics

When I was studying the perfect conductor scattering (**Section 10.1**) in Jackson's book, I was confused by the calculation for magnetic dipole induced by the incident wave. He simply said like "set the $\mu$=0 in **equation (5.115)**......"

Actually, **equation (5.115)** 
$$
 M=\frac{3}{\mu_0}\frac{\mu-\mu_0}{\mu+2\mu_0}B_0
$$
is derived under the boundary condition that the surface current=0, i.e. the tangential component of **H** is continuous. But for perfect conductor, this condition is not valid. So any body can help me to figure out how can I get the magnetic dipole in this situation? Thanks.